# Some questions about using python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

Some questions about using python-telegram-bot

I'm using python-telegram-bot to create a telegram bot.

I want to forward a graphic message (similar to the one below) to the robot, and the robot removes the image and returns the text.

I didn't find an example in the official documentation.

I hope someone can help me.

[image]

I read about Combining filters，like `handler = MessageHandler(Filters.forwarded & Filters.photo, callback)`

but I don't know how to use them to separate images and text

Comment: Please change your title "Some questions about using python-telegram-bot" to something pertaining more to the problem, so that this problem can be better searched - consider maybe "How to forward a graphic message to a bot and return the text.". Details about deleting the image can be determined by other users asking questions or you including it in the problem body (which you did).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sloved it

just use the code below

```
def callback(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    print(update.message.caption)
```

then python will print out the text

don't forget to import `CallbackContext` and `Updater`